# Права на запись файлов

Tags: vds, centos, chmod

Впервые взял VDS, ОС - Centos, виртуализация - KVM, опыта мало, с горем пополам сделал основные настройки, перенёс несколько сайтов, которые до этого были на виртуальном хосте.

На виртуальном хостинге, для каталогов chmod был 755 и при этом файлы загружались туда без проблем. После переноса, файлы загружаются в нужные каталоги, только если на них установить права 777, что не есть хорошо. Но даже, если на это закрыть глаза (*чего сделать не получается*), то проблему не решить с файлами, которые должны лежать и перезаписываться/создаваться в корне сайта, например, sitemap.xml.

Как справиться с данной задачей? Как оставить права 755, но при этом дать возможность записи файлов владельцу сайта в том числе и создание файлов в корне?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользоваться командой chown.

Comment: То есть, прописывать вручную для каждого пользователя? Неужели нет способа, чтоб при добавлении нового пользователя, такие права владельца создавались бы автоматом? Даже при моем мизерном опыте в администрировании вериться мало.

Comment: Нет. Вам нужно прописать владельца каталога и всех подкаталогов пользователя от которого запущен ftp (chown -R user:group)

Comment: Возможно, что я не полностью конкретизировал. Попробую уточнить. Добавляю нового пользователя через DirectAdmin. При этом создается каталог (в том числе *public_html*), к которому он имеет доступ по FTP. По FTP, если зайти под владельцем, то можно и создавать файлы, и редактировать, и удалять. А вот скрипты, которые создают/перезаписывают файлы - этого сделать не могут. Интуитивно чувствую, что это связано с этим.P.S. Не знаю, может это будет полезным дополнением, но если в каталоге пользователя, запустить команду ls -l, то выдает примерно следующее:

Comment: drwx--x--x  8 username username 4096 Oct 12 00:10 .    drwx--x--x  3 username username 4096 Oct 11 13:43 ..    drwxr-xr-x  2 username username 4096 Oct 11 13:43 .htpasswd    drwx------  2 username username 4096 Oct 21 00:11 logs    drwxr-xr-x  2 username username 4096 Oct 11 13:43 private_html    drwx--x--x  3 username username 4096 Oct 11 13:43 public_ftp    drwxr-xr-x 10 username username 4096 Oct 12 02:20 public_html    drwxr-xr-x  2 username username 4096 Oct 12 00:10 stats

Comment: > скрипты, которые создают/перезаписывают файлы - этого сделать не могутчто за скрипты? они как-то связаны с DirectAdmin?

Comment: Нет. Это скрипты  сайтов, которые писал я, написаны на PHP (*не использую никаких CMS*). К примеру, тот же sitemap - генерируется автоматически и перезаписывается по определенным событиям, файловый кеш (некоторые данные в json-формате), загрузка графических файлов etc.

Comment: скрипты запускаются от чьего имени? может их запускать от username, либо username добавить в группу apache и её же назначить группой владельцев public_html?Просто предлагаю кучу вариантов, как пищу для размышления.

Comment: Можно же в конфиге сервера FTP задать необходимые права загружаемым файлам. Или я не о том?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:на папки права 775На файлы права 664

- Внесение юзера в соотвестствующую группу. А по логике распределения прав то вёс верно.

Answer (score 0):

массово сменить права на файлы в разных папках через ssh

```
chmod -R xxx file
-r — рекурсивно, т.е. включая все папки и файлы в указанной папке
ххх = набор прав для доступа к файлу/папке (0555, 0777 и пр.)
file = папка или файл. Для смены массово прав по всему домену нужно 
в данном случае указывать именно самую верхнуюю папку (/published/ или /www/ и т.д.)
```

Примеры:

```
проставить права 644 только на один файл:
chmod -R 644 /var/www/index.php

проставить права 644 только на все фаилы и папки в директории:
chmod -R 644 /var/www/*

проставить права 644 только на одну папку:
chmod -R 644 /var/www/

проставить права 644 только на файлы:
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

проставить права 755 только на каталоги:
find /path/to/dir -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
```

сменить владельца chmod файлов и папок по ssh с вложенностью:

```
chown -R Пользователь:Группа /путь_к_каталогу/
```